# How to remove "switch user" button on Windows 7 lock screen?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to remove the "switch user" button shown in the photo below?  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This is just asking about the button.

Comment: Yet; The solution is the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1:

Delete all other user accounts on the system.

Option 2:

Use a machine policy to hide fast user switching.

- Start > Run > type `gpedit.msc` and hit enter.
- Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon and enable "*Hide entry points for Fast User Switching*".
- Start > Run > type `gpupdate /force` and hit enter.
- If it doesn't make you, reboot to have the setting take effect.

If you're using a Home/non-Pro version of Windows where the policy editor is missing, you can apply the same policy manually by editing the registry directly:

- Start > Run > type `regedit.exe` and hit enter.
- Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.
- Create a DWORD (32-bit) Value named **HideFastUserSwitching** (right-click on the right side of the editor and select **New** > **DWORD(32bit) Value**.
- Set the Value data for **HideFastUserSwitching** to **1**.
- Exit Regedit and reboot the machine.

[Source for registry version](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-xp-and-windows-vista/)

Comment: One might want to point out.  This only works if you have a version of Windows that has `gpedit.msc` **Windows 7 Home Premium** for instance does not.  There are [ways](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63025-ctrl-alt-del-start-menu-add-remove-switch-user.html) around that limitation though

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, it'd be nice if OPs told us that info eh? ;) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Indeedway.  Iway aysay eway artstay alkingtay ikelay isthay otay osethay atthay orgetfay otay elltay usway importantway 
informationway ikelay ethay ersionvay ofway Indowsway eythay 
areway usingway.

Comment: @Ramhound Youryay igpay atinlay isyay ongstray. [isThay anslatortray](http://www.wordplays.com/pig-latin) elpedhay. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And sorry I didn't clarify, but I am using Win7 Ultimate.  But this way other people who don't have Ultimate can use this method.